# swift 2-unexpectedly found nil while accessing array of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm taking online course with swift 1. These code are alright at 1 but show runtime error at 2.

MusicLibrary.swift

```
let library = [
    [
        "title": "Rise and Shine",
        "description": "Get your morning going by singing along to these classic tracks as you hit the shower bright and early!",
        "icon": "coffee.pdf",
        "largeIcon": "coffee_large.pdf",
        "backgroundColor": ["red": 255, "green": 204, "blue": 51, "alpha": 1.0],
        "artists": ["American Authors", "Vacationer", "Matt and Kim", "MGMT", "Echosmith", "Tokyo Police Club", "La Femme"]
    ]
```

Playlist.swift

```
    init(index: Int) {
    let musicLibrary = MusicLibrary().library
    let playlistDictionary = musicLibrary[index]

    title = playlistDictionary["title"] as String!
    description = playlistDictionary["description"] as String!

    let iconName = playlistDictionary["icon"] as String!
    icon = UIImage(named: iconName!)

    let largeIconName = playlistDictionary["largeIcon"] as String!
    largeIcon = UIImage(named: largeIconName!)

    artists += playlistDictionary["artist"] as [String]
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `index` ?

Comment: when assign used key "artists", but when accessing using the key "artist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what 's error?

in swift 2 you must code:

```
if let _title = playlistDictionary["title"] as? String{
   self.title = _title
}
```

or if playlistDictionary is optional :

```
if let _title = playlistDictionary?["title"] as? String{
   self.title = _title
}
```

Comment: Error is    'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String!'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you get "artist"(String) instead of "artists"(Array). Anyway, with your code, can fix like this:

```
   if objects.objectForKey("artist") != nil
   {
      let artist = playlistDictionary("artist") as [String]
       artists += artist
   }
```

Comment: These errors show bro

Use of unsolved identifier 'objects'
Cannot call value of non functional type 'NSDictionary'

Answer (score 0):

```
let library:[Dictionary<String,Any>] = [
    [
        "title": "Rise and Shine",
        "description": "Get your morning going by singing along to these classic tracks as you hit the shower bright and early!",
        "icon": "coffee.pdf",
        "largeIcon": "coffee_large.pdf",
        "backgroundColor": ["red": 255, "green": 204, "blue": 51, "alpha": 1.0],
        "artists": ["_American Authors", "_Vacationer", "_Matt and Kim", "_MGMT", "_Echosmith", "_Tokyo Police Club", "_La Femme"]
    ],
    [
        "title": "Rise and Shine",
        "description": "Get your morning going by singing along to these classic tracks as you hit the shower bright and early!",
        "icon": "coffee.pdf",
        "largeIcon": "coffee_large.pdf",
        "backgroundColor": ["red": 255, "green": 204, "blue": 51, "alpha": 1.0],
        "artists": ["American Authors", "Vacationer", "Matt and Kim", "MGMT", "Echosmith", "Tokyo Police Club", "La Femme"]
    ]
]


var artists: [String] = []
library.forEach { (dict) -> () in
    if let arr = dict["artists"] as? [String] {
        artists += arr
    }
}
print(artists)
/*
["_American Authors", "_Vacationer", "_Matt and Kim", "_MGMT", "_Echosmith", "_Tokyo Police Club", "_La Femme", "American Authors", "Vacationer", "Matt and Kim", "MGMT", "Echosmith", "Tokyo Police Club", "La Femme"]

*/
```

if your library is [NSDictionary] it still works the same way